# Wampserver3 - How to add an old PHP version

Tags: wampserver, php-5.2, wamp3

I just upgrade to wampserver3.0.4 to get php5.6, php7 and new functionalities but I got some projects in 5.2 (upgrade php is not a possibility)

There is no more the button 'get more' in php version and I can't figure how I can add my old 5.2 version to my panel.

Any suggestions?

Comment: PHP 5.2 reached End of Life [5 years, 7 months ago](http://php.net/eol.php). It does not receive security updates. **Do not use it**. Fix the code to work with a supported version of PHP instead.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I know It's deprecated but we have to deal with it.

Comment: Please note that my comment is marked as a comment and not as an answer before complaining that it isn't an answer.

Comment: Ok sorry you right I should say "this comment doesn't help". I wrote in my post that upgrading php was not an option, unfortunately... Sometimes you have to deal with old servers, resources missing, customer is dumb, etc... Thank you anyway for your interest.